# C# async method called concurrently should wait for the first operation to complete

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that looks like

```
public async Task<OpenResult> openAsync()
```

I want to do something like if there is a current call to openAsync in the process of getting executed, I would like to place any calls to OpenAsync be added to a queue.

When the first call completes, I want to complete all the ones in the queue with the result of the first call.

What’s the way to achieve this in C#

Comment: The async calls are independent between themselves. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Can you provide some more information please?

Comment: Why *doesn't* the code await for the method to complete? How is `openAsync` called? Is there a missing `await` perhaps? There's no need for any queues, that's how Tasks already work.

Comment: there are two main scenarios with `async`; 1) the *caller* worries about concurrency, and only calls methods appropriately, awaiting between them - usually from a single caller logical flow; 2) the *type* worries about concurrency, with logical queues (and often multiple parallel caller flows against the same instance); the first is **much, much** easier to implement and understand, and is *by far* the majority usage; the second is *really quite hard*; are you sure you need that? can you explain *why* you need that? it *can* be done, but ... it is a *huge* thing to explain and do

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this question.  We do not know how classes are designed and where this method is located and where the callers are located and who is going to add entries to queue.   Did you consider using Singleton class which has only this method and runs this method synchronously ?

Comment: it could also be a *lot* easier to implement this if it can be reduced to something like a semaphore-slim around access, so that only one concurrent caller is permitted (with any other concurrent callers waiting on the semaphore)

Comment: So after the first call completes and all of the other callers who were waiting are fed back the result, what happens to the *next* caller to the method?

Comment: Please, explain what you want to do. The question is too vague  - it could be asking for anything. Perhaps there's a missing `await`? Or you want to throttle multiple concurrent calls, something that can be done with ActionBlock, ReactiveX or System.Threading.Channels.

Answer (score 2):

*Usually*, this kind of detail is left to the caller, i.e. by making the caller `await` appropriately and only call methods when they *should* call methods. However, if you *must* do this, one simple way is via a semaphore; consider:

```cs
class HazProtected
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task<OpenResult> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            return await DoOpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }
    }

    private async Task<OpenResult> DoOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ... your real code here
    }
}
```

The code in `OpenAsync` ensures that only one concurrent async caller can be attempting to open it at a time. When there is a conflict, callers are held asynchronously until the semaphore can be acquired. There is a complication, though; `SempahoreSlim` has some known problems on .NET Framework (resolved in .NET Core) when there are both asynchronous *and* synchronous semaphore acquisitions at the same time - [which can lead to a spiral of death](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/02/fun-with-spiral-of-death.html).

---

In more *complex* scenarios, it is possible to write your own queue of pending callers; this is a very very exotic scenario and should *usually* not be attempted unless you understand exactly why you're doing it!